# Do all functions from a static library get linked into the final executable?

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries

I am new to static libraries and just want to make 100% sure that what i'm doing is right. To make it short, i'll try to explain my question with this simple example:

If in `mylib.a` i have defined the following functions:

```
int f1 (int a, int b) {/*some code here...*/}
int f2 (int a, int b) {/*some code here...*/}
int f3 (int a, int b) {/*some code here...*/}
// we also suppose that f1 does not call f2 or f3.
```

In my project i linked `mylib.a` but only used `f1`. Would `f2` and `f3` get into the final executable too?

I have a feeling that this is also compiler specific, but let's consider that we only talk about `GCC` here. I'll find any specific information about other compilers like `MSVC compiler` and how they treat this problem valuable since i want to make my libraries as compatible as i can.

---

I also find the explination given on wikipedia vague since i do not find it clear *WHO* includes `those parts of the library...`. Also, the expression`it is enough to include` doesen't give me confidence that only and only the code needed is included.

> With static linking, it is enough to include those parts of the library that are directly and indirectly referenced by the target executable (or target library). With dynamic libraries, the entire library is loaded, as it is not known in advance which functions will be invoked by applications.

Comment: It is toolchain specific, but all modern toolchains will discard unused functions.

Comment: @RaymondChen: you say "discard unused functions" — do you mean something along the lines of "not include object files that do not satisfy an unsatisfied reference", or do you mean that modern toolchains slice and dice object files to avoid including specific functions (and objects?) that are not needed?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Neither. Linkers have always included object files in order to satisfy references. What's new is that once all references are satisfied, they then slice apart the object files and remove things that are not used. In the above example, an external reference to f1 will pull in f2 and f3 (and require resolution of the things that f2 and f3 refer to). Once all references are resolved, the "discard unused functions" step will remove f2 and f3. Note that this is different from "not pulling in f2 and f3 at all." f2 and f3 get included, and then are later removed.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Interesting — can you provide pointers on where the 'post-link slicing' of object code is documented?  Does the technique have a searchable name?  Which compilers provide that functionality?

Comment: [gcc -ffunction-sections](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Compilation-options.html), msvc [/Gy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gy-enable-function-level-linking?view=vs-2019) + [/opt:ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/opt-optimizations?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Traditionally, when you link with a static library, each object file in the library that satisfies a currently unsatisfied reference will be included in the executable.  Any references from the selected object files within the library will also be picked up, repeating until there are no more object files that can satisfy any unsatisfied references.  The linking process then moves on to the next library in the list.

If there are still unresolved reference when it reaches the end of the last library, the linker generates error messages about undefined external references.

Comment: So basically it sees each object file in the library as an atomic unit. So, either all the function (including used and unused) from the object file are loaded or none are?

Comment: @User10482 — yes; that's an accurate summary.