# Net addition in .text/.data after linking a static library is much more than size of .text/.data in the static library

Tags: c, linker, static-libraries, compiler-optimization, linker-flags

I have compiled a static library and size -t summary is like this

```
 text      data     bss     dec     hex filename
 100166    2944     950  104060   1967c (TOTALS)
```

But when this library is linked with an executable, net addition in .text/.data/.bss in the final binary is much more than the sizes of these sections in the static library. As an example, size of .data/.bss is increased by 8k in the binary while the linked library has a combined .data/.bss size of 4k.

As per my understanding, all this bloat is caused by the presence of relocation symbols in the static library. Can anyone confirm on this and is there a way to reduce the memory footprint of the executable?

Comment: Linking with a static library only pulls in parts of the library you actually use.  (`.o` files from the library which contain symbols your main program actually uses. And in turn other files they need, until all the dependencies are satisfied.)  [Do all functions from a static library get linked into the final executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60861129)

Comment: Oh wait a minute, you're saying that it's using up *more* space than the total size, not less.  But you're talking about small totals like 4k or 8k (1 or 2 pages).  Could that just be page granularity and alignment padding?  Like if including a little bit more code bumped it past a 4k boundary?  Relocation symbols and so on are metadata, not part of the sizes that `size` shows.  Can you include actual numbers for all the things you're talking about, like the object files before linking, and the linked executable?

Comment: @Peter Cordes - Yes, it is taking more _space_ than the total size. I don't think this is related to paging etc as .text space increase is even many times higher.  Can you specify what exact details you need to take it further?

Comment: Did you test it with a very small program and a very small library, which might either reveal more information or create a [mre] you could share with us? What about a very small program with the subject library or the subject program with a very small library? What compiler, what linker, what operating system, what link options?

Comment: I was thinking at least the output of `size` on all the linker inputs (the non-library part), and on the final output.  And the build commands.  Did you perhaps statically link libc into your program by using `-static`?

Comment: The size reported by `size` doesn't include debugging or relocation information.  Those probably account for most of the difference.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler - I tried using readelf -a which shows all debugging and relocation information but haven't found a smart way yet to come up with a full size. Also, how this debugging/relocation information would affect the size of the resulting binary?

Comment: Debug info and the symbol table aren't in .data, .text, or .bss.  I thought you said the sizes of .data and .bss were larger than expected in the linked executable, not the size of the file on disk.  That's a separate thing.  (Especially since .bss doesn't take any size in the executable.)

Comment: Are you accounting for the size of the CRT start files that get statically linked into your executable?  e.g. if I compile a trivial hello.c, I get text size 133 bytes (data/bss = 0), but linking into a dynamic executable I get text 1500, data 584, bss 8.