# How do i link only desired functions from static library?

Tags: c, assembly, static-libraries, preprocessor

I want to link only Print_String and Exit functions from this assembly GNU/as x64 library (that actually contains 20+ functions):

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.section .text
.global Exit
Exit:
#Exit definition

.global Print_String
Print_String:
#Print_String definition

...other functions (20)
```

to this c code:

```
#define PRINT_STRING
#define EXIT

void _start() {
Print_String("Hello, World!");
Exit(0);
}
```

Normal linking just includes all 20+ functions with whole definitions, I would rather stick with static lib instead of dynamic

Comment: Put each function in a separate `.o` file (normally from a separate `.S` file).  [Do all functions from a static library get linked into the final executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60861129) .   Or I think there might be something you can do like `gcc -ffunction-sections` and link with `--gc-sections` to remove unused sections. So `.section .text.something` I guess.  [How do I include only used symbols when statically linking with gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5307348) / [Does gnu ld link in whole object files or only the needed functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13525889)